# what is the best iframe modal box

Tags: jquery

i want a internal popup or nice modal box which contains an iframe ( i should able to set the width and height ) and which is easy to install , and has no too much files.

i don't prefer lightbox currently.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Colorbox](http://colorpowered.com/colorbox/) is nice.

Comment: Thanks, it's exactely what i'm looking for :)